# Sorting in Dictionary C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I Have one Dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, string> rList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
rList .Add("/a/b/c", "35");
rList .Add("/a/c/f/v", "25");
rList .Add("/a/r/d/c/r/v", "29");
rList .Add("/a", "21");
rList .Add("/a/f, "84");
```

I just want to sort this Dictionary based on the number of number of '/' present in the key. my expected out put is ,

```
("/a/r/d/c/r/v", "29")
("/a/c/f/v", "25")
("/a/b/c", "35")
("/a/f, "84")
("/a", "21")
```

Comment: This post explains answer to your question 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667684/sorting-in-dictionary-c-sharp

Comment: @rajkumarts: You just linked to this question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` type is an unordered collection in .Net.  If you want ordering then you need to use `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>` instead and provide a custom `IComparer<string>` which counts the `/` values in the string.

```
sealed class SlashComparer : IComparer<string> { 
  static int CountSlashes(string str) { 
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) { 
      return 0;
    }

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++) {
      if (str[i] == '/') {
         count++;
      }
    }
    return count;
  }

  public int Compare(string left, string right) { 
    int leftCount = CountSlashes(left);
    int rightCount = CountSlashes(right);
    return rightCount - leftCount;
  }
}
```

To use with a `SortedDictionary` the only thing you need to change is the declaration

```
var comparer = new SlashComparer();
var rList = new SortedDictionary<string, string>(comparer);
```

The rest of the code can remain the same

Comment: thanks JaredPar , can you please provide a sample code to work with SortedDictionary .

Answer (score 3):

As [JaredPar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23283/jaredpar) answered already `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` content has no order specified. However, you can get `List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` with desired order:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> results = rList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Key.Count(c => c == '/')).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 var result = rList.OrderBy(input => input.Key.Select(c => c == '/').Count()).Reverse().ToList();
```

Comment: This won't work.  The final product here is a `Dictionary<Tkey, TValue>` which is always unordered. The OP wants an ordered value

Comment: As long as it ends with a `ToDictionary` call it will be wrong.  A `Dictionary` is **always** unordered.  It doesn't matter what order you add the values into the dictionary.  They are allowed to come back out in a different one during enumeration

Answer (score 0):

from linqpad:

```
void Main()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> rList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    rList .Add("/a/b/c", "35");
    rList .Add("/a/c/f/v", "25");
    rList .Add("/a/r/d/c/r/v", "29");
    rList .Add("/a", "21");
    rList .Add("/a/f", "84");

    var x = from a in rList
        let i = a.Key.ToCharArray().Count (k => k.Equals('/') )
        orderby i descending
        select a;

    x.Dump();
}
```